# Is there a way to make 1 Textwatcher for 2 editTexts?

Tags: kotlin

Is there a way to unite the 2 TextWatchers' variables?
I can't keep the variables outside the TextWatcher.
And i can't modify or save variables during the textwatcher,and setText crushes my App.

```
 var x: Int = 0
 var y: Int = 0
 editText1.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        }
        override fun beforeTextChanged(
            s: CharSequence?,
            start: Int,
            count: Int,
            after: Int
        ) {
        }
        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            y= y+1
            if (editText.text.length < 8 && x > 6) {
                editText.error = "Number Should Have At Least 8 Digits"
            }
            }
    })
   editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        }
        override fun beforeTextChanged(
            s: CharSequence?,
            start: Int,
            count: Int,
            after: Int
        ) {
        }
        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            x = x+1
            if (editText.text.length < 6 && y > 8) {
                editText.error = "Password Needs To Be 6 Characters"
                login.isEnabled = false
            }

            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Why can't you keep variables outside the TextWatchers? Which variables?

Comment: I tried var x = 0, in text changed x = x+1 outside the variable x was equal 0

Comment: By the way thank you for your help.

Comment: Which variables?  There's no `x` in your example — nor any other local variables.  Can you edit your example to show what you're trying to do?

Comment: Edited the variables i am trying to get, for some reason they are equal 0 even after i change my text.

Comment: How are you checking that their value is zero?

Comment: if(x > 0 && y > 0)

{
login.isEnabled = true
}